# Find Methods and Showing Results in Template

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, pdo, fat-free-framework

- I'm building a site using a MySQL DB with 265 fields, and 5000+ rows in the
  DB;
- I can load() a specific record easily, no problems.
- When using find(), afind(), and even "select()", template will show
  blank lines or lines with "filler" text, with the correct number of
  rows for the query results, but no text/data from the DB itself;
- Same problem whether using objects or simply arrays from result (afind() and find()). I've
  copied/pasted the code verbatim from examples and from documentation, with only the DB specific items changed. Still, no luck.

**CODE IN PHP FILE (function from CLASS):**

```
static function home() {
    $featured=new Axon('boats');
    $F3::set('boatlist',$featured->afind('D_CustomerID=173'));
    F3::set('content',TEMPLATE_DIR .'/home.html');
    echo Template::serve(TEMPLATE_DIR .'/layout.html');

}
```

**TEMPLATE home.html:**

```
<div class="span8">
<h3>
    Featured Boats
</h3>
<F3:repeat group="{{@boatlist}}" value="{{@boat}}">
<div style="margin-left: 2em" class="thumbnails">
    <p>
        <a href="boat/{{@boat['D_BoatNum']}}">{{(trim(@boat['D_Description']))}}</a> by {{@boat['D_CustomerID']}}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{@boat['D_Price']}}
    </p>
</div>
</F3:repeat>
</div>
```

The number of rows this produces coincides with the correct number of rows in the DB. However, the actual data from each field does not show.

Comment: FIXED: I simply upgraded F3 to 2.0.13 from 2.0.11. That fixed it. DOH! I thought I had the latest version.

Comment: Add as answer and accept, please.